# Android 2.3.3 internet works on my Galaxy S but not on my Galaxy Tab ? (Permissions?)

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection, ui-thread

I have this strange problem. I am retrieving twitters and it works on the Emulator and also on my Samsung Galaxy S but it doesn't work on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 ?

Same app installed on both the phone and the tab. Generated from Eclipse so no debugging or anything.

Different permissions needed?

This is the code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
```

and this is the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Patrick, did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I swear, this question is asked everyday here on StackOverflow. :)

The problem is that you are performing a network access on the main UI thread. Android 3.0 and above will crash your application (i.e. the system will throw a `NetworkAccessOnMainThread` exception) if you attempt to perform an HTTP request on the main thread. You need to wrap your HTTP request in an `AsyncTask` (or a `Thread` of some sorts) to ensure that you don't block the UI thread.

Read my blog post on the subject:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: Haha, I am not even joking. I answer this question 4-5 times a week. Half of my favorite SO tags are HTTP-related, despite not knowing a thing about http requests :)

Comment: Stupid Android and their "so" called backwards compatibility! ;-)

Comment: I somewhat agree... I think it would have been nice if someone had at least documented the change on the developers site. That said, it's something you should never, ever do so I agree that it should throw an exception :)

Answer (score 3):

Use This Code, It works for me.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    }
```